# How to build static Qt libraries for Windows and use them with Qt Creator

Tags: windows, qt, static, qt-creator, libraries

I've downloaded the following Qt sources:
 http://download.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3.zip
and tried to setup a distribution with static libraries using MS VC 2010.

Beforehand I did read the following articles:

http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_static_Qt_on_Windows

http://www.formortals.com/build-qt-static-small-microsoft-intel-gcc-compiler

I modified the mkspecs\win32-msvc2010\qmake.conf - update the QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE key to use the MT option instead of MD.
After that I executed the following command line from the VC 2010 command prompt:

```
   configure -platform win32-msvc2010 -static -release
```

When that has finished I was asked to simply run nmake, which I did.
After that I tried to add the qmake from the the static libs distribution folder to Qt Creator (Tools/Options - Qt section). It was unsuccessful - got "Failed to detect ABI(s) used by the Qt version" message by Qt Creator.

I also tried (on a clean distribution) modifying the qmake/Makefile.win32 file before running the configure command - added /MT option to the CFLAGS_BARE definition, but got the same error message in Qt Creator.

I'm using Qt Creator 2.3. - installed separately.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the stable release of 2.3 or a release candidate / beta version of Qt Creator? Check Help->About Qt Creator for the version. If it is something like 2.x.xx try updating to a newer version of Qt Creator.

The issue you described was listed as a bug for 2.2.0 and was set to fixed for 2.3.0:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-4771

If you are already using a newer version and still have that issue, I've read something about putting a QtCore4.dll next to the .lib files. Qt Creator will then find the Qt version based on that dll, but will use the .libs for linking anyway.

Comment: I'm using the Qt creator that could be found here
  [link](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/downloads#qt-creator)
The actual address is
  [link](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator/qt-creator-win-opensource-2.3.1.exe)

Comment: If you posted this link to tell me you are using the current version there (2.3.1), try the .dll thing I posted

Comment: I did take the QtCor4.dll from a distribution built with dynamic qt libs
That's odd, it seems to be working - the Qt creator did recognize the qmake from the statically built distribution, even though I only a modified the qmake.conf -
       QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O1 -Og  -GL -MD

Comment: I'll now try to build Qt libs with MT flag instead of MD, using that same workaround with the QtCore dll. Hopefully it will work again.

Answer (score -1):

in my case.

qt 5.7.1 has /qt5.7.1/qtbase/qmake/project.o file

but qt 5.8.0 no exist project.o file

i'm newbie so waiting for patch.

:add

look for some infomation of ci called 'conan'

in github qt-webkit using conan build.

Comment: Can you explai a bit more?