# How to link against Qt libraries built from source within Qt Creator under Windows?

Tags: qt, linker

I'm running **Qt Creator 2.4.1** under **Windows 7**. It works fine with the `.dll` libraries shipped with the SDK under `C:\QtSDK`

Recently, I built [4.8.2 libraries](http://releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source/qt-win-opensource-4.8.2-mingw.exe) from source under `C:\qt-source` like this:

```
configure -platform win32-g++ -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-webkit \
          -fast -debug -opensource -shared -no-qt3support -no-sql-sqlite \
          -no-openvg -no-gif -no-libpng -no-libmng -no-libtiff -no-libjpeg \
          -no-script -no-scripttools -nomake examples -nomake demos -no-xmlpatterns 
mingw32-make
```

To link against the new libraries, I added Manual Qt 4.8.2 `C:\qt-source\4.8.2\bin\qmake.exe` under Tools > Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions. However, Qt Creator still seems to pick up .dll libs from `C:\QtSDK`

Comment: This might seem duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142047/how-to-build-static-qt-libraries-for-windows-and-use-them-with-qt-creator, but it's not. I am facing no "Failed to detect ABI(s) used by the Qt version" error - so this is a different question

Comment: Did you switch your project to use the new Qt install?

Comment: You probably have some environment variables for library paths that are set to the old location.

Comment: Which environment variables exactly? And how do I check the values of the variables picked up by Qt Creator?

Comment: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-run-settings.html Click at the Details button in Run Environment. It's probably the PATH variable.

Comment: The environment variables seem to be set fine. Strangely enough, when I use static libraries, Qt Creator picks them up correctly.